# Converting files to binary taking hours - Node.js

Tags: node.js, binary, buffer

I'm reading csv data and then writing it to binary.  However, it seems the process of reading in a csv file, converting each data point to a float, and then writing that data to a file takes an insane amount of time.  What am I doing wrong and how can I speed this up?

Is this a limitation on node?  Should I be using a different language?

```js
var csvStream = csv.createWriteStream({headers: true});
var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(csvPath);
csvStream.pipe(writeStream);
var binaryWriteStream = fs.createWriteStream(binaryPath, {'flags': 'a'});
Object.keys(dataSources).map(function (dataSource) {
    firstPromise = firstPromise.then(function () {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var allTheData = [];
            var readStream = fs.createReadStream(dataSource);
            //stream contents into csv reader
            csv.fromStream(readStream, {delimiter: delimiterCharacter}).on("data", function (data) {
                //get all data
                allTheData.push(data);
            }).on("end", function () {
                    var promise = Promise.resolve();
                    //for each row
                    allTheData.map(function (someData) {
                        promise = promise.then(function () {
                            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                                var someOtherPromise = Promise.resolve();
                                //preallocate buffer
                                var buf = Buffer.allocUnsafe(4 * someData.length);
                                var counter = 0;
                                //for each individual data sample
                                someData.map(function (data) {
                                    someOtherPromise = someOtherPromise.then(function () {
                                        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                                            //convert to float
                                            buf.writeFloatLE(data, counter * 4);
                                            counter++;
                                            resolve();
                                        });
                                    });
                                });
                                someOtherPromise.then(function () {
                                    //write buffer to file
                                    binaryWriteStream.write(buf);
                                    resolve();
                                });
                                someOtherPromise.catch(function (err) {
                                    console.log(err);
                                    reject(err);
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    });
                    promise.then(function () {
                        resolve();
                    });
                    promise.catch(function (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        reject(err);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

TLDR:

```
reading in csv data from files in sequence
allocating and converting the csv data into binary line by line
writing it to a file
```

With this methodology it takes me **five hours** to read **614 files** and subsequently **read, allocate, convert, and write 99 million samples** to a single unified binary file.

Comment: Aren't Promises there to get rid of callback hell? Also, what is `promises`? `someOtherPromise`? `someData`?

Comment: @DrakaSAN i'm using promises in this instance for control flow.  I'll clean it up. Similarly 'promise' and 'someOtherPromise' all for sequential execution.